# coldfusion sessionid not being created

Tags: coldfusion, session-variables, session-state, sessionid, application.cfc

I have a ColdFusion 9 application using an `application.cfc` and it creates the session like it should but when I dump the session there is a cfid and a cftoken and sometimes the urltoken but no sessionid and I can not reference the `SESSION.SessionID` variable in my code as it says it is undefined.

What would cause it to creat the cfid and the cftoken just fine but no sessionid?

```
<cfset THIS.Name = "AppNameRedacted" /> 
<cfset THIS.ApplicationTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 2, 0, 0, 0 ) /> 
<cfset THIS.SessionManagement = true /> 
<cfset THIS.SessionTimeout = CreateTimeSpan( 0, 2, 30, 0 ) /> 
<cfset THIS.SetClientCookies = true />
```

**EDIT: onSessionStart() function**

```
<cffunction name="OnSessionStart" access="public" returntype="void" output="false" hint="Fires when the session is first created."> 
    <cfset var LOCAL = {} /> 
    <cfset LOCAL.CFID = SESSION.CFID /> 
    <cfset LOCAL.CFTOKEN = SESSION.CFTOKEN /> 
    <!--- Clear the session. ---> 
    <cfset StructClear( SESSION ) /> 
    <cfset SESSION.CFID = LOCAL.CFID /> 
    <cfset SESSION.CFTOKEN = LOCAL.CFTOKEN /> 
    <!--- Return out. ---> 
    <cfreturn /> 
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Can you provide a repro case that demonstrates this? Should just need an Application.cfc with the relevant app settings, and `onRequestStart()` with a `writeDump(session)` in it. Is it CF9 or 9.0.1 or 9.0.2? Windows or *nix?

Comment: @Renshi - After you move the code [into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27516742/edit), you can delete the redundant comments.

Comment: It is not that the key is not created. You are deleting it (and any other keys in the session scope) when you call `StructClear`. That is why it is undefined later on.

Comment: @Leigh is right,but why are you setting the session up like that anyway?

Comment: I can't remember where I got it from but it was an application.cfc example. Maybe Ray Camden or Ben Nadal example code. The structclear does make sense though. I'll play with that.

Comment: As far as I can tell all of the code in the `onSessionStart` function seems to be redundant. If you remove this code and then put <cfdump var="#session#"> into the function you should see that the session structure already contains CFID, CFTOKEN and SESSIONID on creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are [the ColdFusion 9 docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7c48.html#WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0c35c-7ff3) that outline what variables you can expect in the session scope and when.

In your posted code, you are doing a structClear() on the session scope which is deleting all variables from it.  The only two variables you're putting back are CFID and CFTOKEN.

Comment: The structclear() turned out to be the issue. Not sure why I didn't see that before. Thank you.